# What is the answer to this analogy?

Tags: language

I was doing some questions and got stuck on this problem.

> Gamble is to risk as...
>
> a. hazard is to peril
>
> b. plot is to predict
>
> c. force is to reject
>
> d. embrace is to encroach
>
> e. battle is to brandish

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: welcome here! sorry, but this seems not on-topic, according to the scope defined in the help center. such off-topic posts may get deleted or closed. please check the help center to see what questions you should/ can ask here on P.SE. happy puzzling! ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton; this sort of question appear regularly on IQ Tests, which sort of makes them a puzzle. If it was maths, x:y::z:?, we have loads of those types of the site.

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry A math problem appearing on an IQ test wouldn’t be a puzzle despite it appearing there. Same for word analogies. This is something to *know* or *recognize*, not something to **solve** via reasoned process. It is off topic here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's:

> (a). GAMBLE is a [synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym) of RISK, as is HAZARD to PERIL. The others aren't synonyms.

Comment: you are encouraging low-quality/ off-topic/ unattributed posts by answering them. please refrain from doing do in the future, and consider deleting this answer. thanks!